# How to return React element value in console?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, google-chrome

This seems so simple but I am having a hard time finding any relevant resources. I am on a website and see the following in the inspector:

[image]

I want to be able write some sort of jQuery expression that will return the array of id's under the "Products" key but can't figure out how to access the values within the created React element.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Just access the DOM element?

Comment: you want to do this outside of react? or inside react?

Comment: How can I access that DOM element? I am not sure it matters if it is inside or outside of React. As long as I am able to insert some sort of expression into the console and for that array to be returned in the console.

Comment: You can write `debugger` before this object, then in source section using `F10` you can reach this object and `right click` on the object and select `Evaluate in console` from the opened popup for seeing the result in console.

Comment: it matters because in your screenshot you are showing us a code inside a script tag and not a rendered `DOM` element. if you know the `id` or `class` or whatever specific selector of the element that will be rendered you can use JS or jQuery to query it. if you are inside react just use a ref .

Comment: https://shop.nordstrom.com/c/paul-smith?origin=productBrandLink

This is the link of the website I am accessing. I want to be able to go into the inspector and return the array of ID's under the "Products" key. Using whatever expression we can. As long as I can insert it into the console and it will return back that array then it is good.

Comment: @Sagivb.g What I can see in that screenshot is exactly what I am seeing in the console, so I assume I need to use a ref? Could exactly do I do that in the console? I have been poking around with something like this but it is incomplete and isn't quite working. I apologize as I am not that familiar with React but appreciate your help! 

`jQuery(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.ProductResultsDesktop))`

Answer (score 1):

The [React Devtools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) might help. It provides a view of the page similar to Chrome's built in 'Elements' view, but specific to React's component hierarchy.

If all you need to see is an array of IDs, you can inspect any component's props and state. If you need to do some kind of javascript manipulation, you can "export" a prop or state item as a global variable accessible in the console.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand from your comments and question, you are looking for a way to debug your react component and display the data that being passed as props.

If this is correct, i advice you to use [react developer tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools).
This way you can inspect a component and see the state and props of it.

Here is an example from the website you posted:

[image]

Comment: So not exactly but I appreciate you taking the time to work on this! Let me explain a little more below. 

This code is not my code, it is the Nordstrom website's code, I'm strictly viewing it through my browser. I had no part in writing the code or React element at all, I am simply viewing it just as a consumer could. I want to be able to scrape the DOM of this website and pull the ID's of all the products on this specific page. I saw that it was packaged nicely already for me in that React element through the inspector so figured it would be easiest to just return that array.